# try catch validation empty text box

Tags: c#, validation, try-catch

Hey so I have the following code which should throw up the errors if the text boxes are empty but it doesn't it just carries on with what it would do were they not and adds an item with 0 or whatever to the list instead, is there a problem with my code?

```
private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            theVisit.name = txtName.Text;
            theVisit.address = txtAddress.Text;
            theVisit.arrival = DateTime.Parse(txtArrival.Text);
            //Update theVisit object to reflect any changes made by the user

            this.Hide();
            //Hide the form
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (txtName.Text == "")
                MessageBox.Show("please enter a customer name");

            if(txtAddress.Text == "") 
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a customer address");

            if(txtArrival.Text == "")
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter an arrival time");
        }
```

NEW

```
if (txtName.Text == "" || txtAddress.Text == "" || txtArrival.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show(" Please enter a value into all boxes");
        else
        theVisit.name = txtName.Text;
        theVisit.address = txtAddress.Text;
        theVisit.arrival = DateTime.Parse(txtArrival.Text);
        //Update theVisit object to reflect any changes made by the user
```

Comment: The only thing there that might throw is DateTime.Parse().  `.Text` on an empty textbox doesn't throw an exception, it just returns an empty string.  Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text)` to check for empty values.

Comment: Is the setters of your theVisit object throws exception? Can you show class implementation of your theVisit object?

Comment: theVisit is a list,  but i think I got it working by putting it in the try not catch section

Comment: "theVisit is a list" what do you mean? The List class has not name, address and arrival properties/fields.

Comment: Nvm I got confused, Also I am an idiot since the reason the error isn't showing for arrival is because It has a default value, Maybe I need to get some sleep or something, I can add the class code to the above post if wanted? although I got the 2 errors to work now I think

Comment: I have edited my code to show something I tried, My new question is WHY does it throw the errors but still add the item to a list without eltting you sort the errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The try-catch-statement is used to catch and handle exceptions. An exception can be thrown, if an index is out of bounds, if members of a variable set to null are accessed, and in many other situations. A `TextBox` being empty is not an error by itself and does not throw an exception.

I suggest you to use a completely different approach. Add an `ErrorProvider` to your form. You find it in the toolbox in the section "Components". Now you can add the following code to your form:

```
private HashSet<Control> errorControls = new HashSet<Control>();

private void ValidateTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox.Text == "") {
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox, (string)textBox.Tag);
        errorControls.Add(textBox);
    } else {
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox, null);
        errorControls.Remove(textBox);
    }
    btnAdd.Enabled = errorControls.Count == 0;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtName.Tag = "Please enter a customer name";
    txtAddress.Tag = "Please enter a customer address";
    errorProvider1.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink;

    ValidateTextBox(txtName, EventArgs.Empty);
    ValidateTextBox(txtAddress, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Select the `ValidateTextBox` method as error handler for the `TextChanged` event of all your textboxes. Insert the desired message in the `Tag` property of the textboxes. Set the `BlinkStyle` property of the `ErrorProvider` to `ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink`. You can do these settings in code or in the form designer.

Now a red error symbol will appear next to empty textboxes. If you hoover the mouse over them, a tooltip with the error message will appear.

---

**UPDATE**

I updated the code above to automatically disable or enable the "Add"-button. Therefore I added a `HashSet` that contains all the controls currently being in an error state. If the set is empty the button is enabled, otherwise disabled.

Comment: Hey, this is good but If the text boxes are empty and the red symbol is there and I press add anyway, It still adds it to the list

Comment: Is there away to avert this? and only add it if all text boxes have stuff in it

Comment: I added code that automatically enables or disables the button. Note that the `Add` and `Remove` methods can be called any number of times for the same value without producing an error.

Answer (score 2):

You should always be avoiding try catch where possible, because of performance hits see example below:

```
        //set name
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text)) MessageBox.Show("please enter a customer name");
        else theVisit.name = txtName.Text;

        //set address
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAddress.Text)) MessageBox.Show("please enter a customer address");
        else theVisit.address = txtAddress.Text;

        //set arrival time
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtArrival.Text)) MessageBox.Show("please enter an arrival time");
        else {

            DateTime dt = default(DateTime);
            bool successParse = DateTime.TryParse(txtArrival.Text, out dt);

            if(!successParse) MessageBox.Show("please enter a valid arrival time");
            else theVisit.arrival = dt;

        }
```

Comment: @TAM No problem. Not quite sure why i've been downvoted for this?